# Stata: c.var1#c.var2 operator invalid version 10.1

Tags: command, stata

I would like to check for moderation with Stata using the interaction # and two continuous variables:

```
version 10.1: xi: regress ................///
c.var1_m#c.var9_m c.var2_m#c.var9_m c.var3_m#c.var9_m ///
var9_m , vce(robust)
```

However, it seems that only the newest Stata versions support this command, as I get the following error message:

```
cvar1_m#c:  operator invalid
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this command as such that it also works with Stata 10.1?

(For example to fix the i. command, I typed in `version 10.1: xi:` and then it also worked on my older version - does something similar exist for `c.`?)

Answer (score 1):

What version of Stata are you using? Stata 10.1, it seems.

Factor variables were introduced in Stata 11. Regardless of what version you are using this is documented accessibly (e.g.) [here](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?whatsnew10to11).

The question that then arises is why are you using the prefix `version 10.1`? 
If you are using version 10.1, that prefix is redundant; otherwise, it can at most set the clock back to the syntax of earlier versions. It should be clear that it cannot possibly set it forward to the syntax of later versions.

A more fundamental mix-up is that (a) syntax using `xi:` as aegis and (b) factor-variable notation are (a) old and (b) new versions of the same idea. They should not be mixed. It may be that this alone is the problem, but experts on either [not me] might wish also to see your complete syntax and/or a reproducible example.

In short, if you are using 10.1, or indeed some earlier version, your only option (other than upgrading your Stata) is to cast your problem in syntax acceptable to `xi:`.